# How do I create FTP usernames using username@domain.com (AMI)

Tags: user-accounts, vsftpd, amazon-lightsail

I have recently moved to lightsail from Godaddy and have some legacy ftp accounts that I need to be maintain, all the ftp account are email addresses associated with the domain name. I have created a separate instance to cater for FTP.

1. On DNS settings ftptest.domain-name.com is pointing to the IP of the
   instance.
2. On lightsail firewall for the instance I removed http
   access and added ports for the ftp.
3. Edited /etc/sysconfig/network to

> NETWORKING=yes
>
> HOSTNAME=domain-name
>
> DOMAINNAME=domain-name.com
>
> NOZEROCONF=yes

4. Edited /etc/hosts to

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
>
> ::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
>
> 3x.xx.xx.1x0 ftptest.domain-name.com ftptest

5. I installed FTP server on the instance (vsftpd: version 2.2.2).
6. Created a new user called test and gave it a password.
7. Tried to login via Filezilla using test@domain-name.com and failed with

> Response: 530 Login incorrect.

8. tried to login as test and was successful.

How do I make it so that I can use test@domain-name.com to login using FTP? The old server which had cpanel did this and I need the same functionality.

Edit 1: I do not get what you mean by 'usernames should include the domain name in themselves" and "@domain.com as part of the account"? I you mean create user with domain included, I get this when I try that:

> sudo useradd test1@domain-name.com
>
> useradd: invalid user name 'test1@domain-name.com'

Comment: My guess is that your usernames should include the domain name in themselves.

Comment: Like Tero my guess is also to have the @domain.com as part of the account. I have a tutorial on adding ftp users to an Amazon Linux instance [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/aws-allow-ssh-sftp-access-server/).

Comment: I do not get what you mean by 'usernames should include the domain name in themselves" and "@domain.com as part of the account"? I you mean create user with domain included, I get this when I try that:

sudo useradd test1@domain-name.com

useradd: invalid user name 'test1@domain-name.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution on my own. What I needed was to install PureFTP and not vsftpd. Since Amazon Linux does not support PureFTP I had to spin up a Ubuntu instance. PureFTP allows creation of virtual users and that is what helped me create a user with @domain-name.com.